# ORDER BY WITH ROLL UP

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.invoice_id,
    invoice_no,
    a.cs_no,
    identity,
    name,
    model,
    body_color,
    lot_no,
    key_no,
    serial_no,
    location,
    buyoff_date,
    received_date,
    tagged_date,
    invoice_date,
    a.pullout_date,
    vin_no,
    engine_no,
    order_no,
    b.approve,
    COUNT(a.cs_no) AS buyoff_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN received_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS received_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tagged_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS tagged_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS invoice_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.pullout_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS pullout_count
FROM buy_off a
LEFT JOIN pull_out b
ON a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id
AND a.cs_no = b.cs_no
WHERE tagged_date IS NOT NULL
AND invoice_date IS NULL
GROUP BY  identity, tagged_date, invoice_id WITH ROLLUP
```

My above code have output like this:

```
invoice_id   identity    tagged_date
1            a           2/5/2015
                        total = 1
2            a           2/6/2015
3            a           2/6/2015
                        total = 2
4            b           2/5/2015
                        total = 1
5            b           2/6/2015
                        total = 1
                  grand total = 5
```

But this is what i want:

```
   invoice_id   identity    tagged_date
    1            a           2/5/2015
    2            a           2/6/2015
    3            a           2/6/2015
                            total = 3
    4            b           2/5/2015
    5            b           2/6/2015
                            total = 2
                      grand total = 5
```

Can you guys please help to achieve the above output.....Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: Your select has at least 20 columns without aggregate functions, but there are only 3 of them in the GROUP BY clause. Are you sure about what values you get for the rest of the columns?

Comment: What happened to `total = 1`?